# Creating window with a NSTextView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access

I wish to create a window without a nib file which consists entirely of an NSTextView.

It should act as a popup but still be modeless.

So far I have two properties:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSWindow *consoleWindow;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSTextView* textView;
```

Here is what my implementation looks like:

```
-(void)doubleAction:(NSOutlineView*)sender
     {

         if(self.currentLogEntry == nil)
         {
             return;
         }

         self.consoleWindow = nil;
         self.textView = nil;


         NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(10.0f, 10.0f, 500.0f, 400.0f);
         self.consoleWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect
                                                          styleMask:( NSResizableWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask)
                                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];


         self.textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self.consoleWindow contentView] frame]];
        [self.textView setString:self.currentLogEntry.value];
        [self.consoleWindow setContentView:self.textView];


         [self.consoleWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
         [self.consoleWindow makeFirstResponder:self.textView];



         NSLog(@"Double clicked");
     }
```

Things have been wired up so I have a list of entries, whenever I double click on an entry the selected entry is loaded into `self.currentLogEntry` and this method is then fired. It works but if I close the window and try to open another entry I get `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`

I think it has something to do with the window not being released properly but I have tried a few things like setting the properties to nil whenever the program enters the doubleAction (as you can see in the code) but that doesn't help.

Any help solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? What bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to actually ask for anything

Comment: If you aren't using nibs, then there is no need to set the property as an IBOutlet.

Comment: That is correct. How will I have access to the nstextview?

Comment: You'll be creating some kind of class to present the window and associated text view, expose it as a property from there.

Comment: I've changed the question after doing some more research and now have a specific problem which I haven't been able to solve, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soulution was to: `[self.consoleWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];`

Here is how the full code ended out being (only relevant parts):
.h:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSWindow *consoleWindow;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSTextView* textView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSScrollView* scrollView;
```

.m:

```
-(void)doubleAction:(NSOutlineView*)sender
     {

         if(self.currentLogEntry == nil)
         {
             return;
         }

         self.consoleWindow = nil;
         self.textView = nil;
         self.scrollView = nil;


         NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(10.0f, 10.0f, 500.0f, 400.0f);
         self.consoleWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect
                                                          styleMask:( NSResizableWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask)
                                                            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
         [self.consoleWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];




         self.scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self.consoleWindow contentView] frame]];

         [self.scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
         [self.scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
         [self.scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
         [self.scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable |
          NSViewHeightSizable];

         NSSize contentSize = [self.scrollView contentSize];


         self.textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,
                                                                    contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
         [self.textView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];
         [self.textView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
         [self.textView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
         [self.textView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
         [self.textView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];

         [[self.textView textContainer]
          setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
         [[self.textView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];



        [self.textView setString:self.currentLogEntry.value];


         [self.scrollView setDocumentView:self.textView];
         [self.consoleWindow setContentView:self.scrollView];
         [self.consoleWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
         [self.consoleWindow makeFirstResponder:self.textView];



         NSLog(@"Double clicked");
     }
```